# Слово "непросто"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нашёл в одном тексте слово "непросто", использованное в смысле "неспроста", "не просто так", "не случайно". Это ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

**Я ведь к тебе пришел не просто так…** [Николай Коляда. Рогатка (1989)]

Сравнить: Я ведь к тебе пришел не просто...

Скорее всего, это просто чисто разговорный вариант (пропущено местоимение ТАК), но написание должно быть раздельным.

Answer (score 1):

**непро́сто** - наречие, также предикатив; неизменяемое.
1. Наречие к прилагательному непростой; *представляя трудности для понимания, решения, осуществления чего-либо*. ***Жить в Москве непросто.***
2.В знач. сказуемого *оценочная характеристика ситуации, чьих-либо действий как являющихся трудными, сложными для выполнения, понимания, осуществления*. ***Сделать это довольно непросто.***
**Синонимы**: заковыристо, замысловато, запутанно, каверзно, мудрено, нелегко, петляво, сложно, трудно, хитро, хитроумно.

**неспроста́** - наречие; неизменяемое.
***Не просто так***, не без оснований, вследствие чего-либо, по какой-либо определённой причине.   ***Все понимали, что собрал он их неспроста.***  Д. А. Гранин, «Зубр», 1987 г.
**Синонимы:** не без причины, нет дыму без огня, не с ветру, не зря, ***не*** ***случайно***, недаром, тут что-то есть.

Контекста Вы не привели, поэтому я предложила к рассмотрению синонимы "непросто", чтобы понять, возможно ли такое использование.
Ну **никак** они - по своему смыслу - **не совпадают** со значением "неспроста", "не просто так", "не случайно"!
Так что, скорее всего, здесь где-то вкралась ошибка.